# Patch data with DataWeave

Tags: dataweave

My goal is to merge the following JSON:

```
{
    lastname:"C.",
    firstname:"Sebastien"
}
```

with

```
{
    lastname:"Coucou",
    age:"N/A"
}
```

Here is what I want as result:

```
{
  "lastname": "Coucou",
  "firstname": "Sebastien",
  "age": "N/A"
}
```

If the key exist I want to update the value, if the key does not exist I want to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method seems to use the `mergeWith()` function from the [Objects](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-objects) module:

```
%dw 2.0
import mergeWith from dw::core::Objects
output application/json

var data={
    lastname:"C.",
    firstname:"Sebastien"
}

var patch ={
    lastname:"Coucou",
    age:"N/A"
}
---
patch mergeWith data
```

Output:

```
{
  "age": "N/A",
  "lastname": "C.",
  "firstname": "Sebastien"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Objects

var data={
    lastname:"C.",
    firstname:"Sebastien"
}

var patch ={
    lastname:"Coucou",
    age:"N/A"
}

---
patch ++ (data -- keySet(patch))
```

As an output:

```
{
  "lastname": "Coucou",
  "age": "N/A",
  "firstname": "Sebastien"
}
```